# How do I set the name of the log file per logger but with the same appender?

Tags: java, spring, logging, logback, appender

I want to have several loggers that are using the same file appender.
I want each log file to have its own specific name that I define (such as requests.log...).
How can I define the log file's name per logger without having to create a file appender for each logger?

This is what my logback-spring.xml looks like right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="pattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level: %msg | request #%X{requestNumber}%n" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="request-logger">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

Comment: A file appender is linked to a file. If you want multiple files, you need multiple appenders. That means that your need ("define the log file's name per logger without having to create a file appender for each logger") simply isn't possible. Why don't you want to create multiple appenders? I mean, it's only 5 lines of code, and you even reuse the pattern.

Comment: Well that's what I did eventually but it seemed like there would be a better option cause it's like repeated code. Each of these appenders is doing (almost) exactly the same thing with the only difference being the log file's name. In my case there are only 3 (almost) identical appenders that I have to add but what if there were 20?

Comment: If those 20 loggers would need 20 different files, then you'd have to use 20 different appenders. One other option would be to create your own appender, that would delegate to these other appenders internally. Less code in your logging config, but you would need to create that class yourself.